# How to write your own throttle rate limit

Tags: python, django, web, django-rest-framework, vs-web-site-project

I want to add features for limiting the number of password reset attempts. For example, Twitter limit the number of password reset attempts 5 times a day.

Comment: What is your specific question?

Comment: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/throttling/